# What is best practice state management for Azure Durable Function App across Activity methods?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

As the title states, I'm trying to move away from the global variables I've defined for my Azure Timer Function which I've recently published to Azure only to be met with an error in the Azure Portal, 'Code + Test' page where I attempt to kick off the function apps Orchestrator function manually.

The error states: **Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask.DurableOrchestrationContext'.**

which is strange considering I also tried removing all string parameters from my Orchestrator to no avail either.

The structure of my project is as follows:

```
namespace MyProject 
{
     public static class ProjMain
     {
          enum dbServerType
          {
           firstExample,
           secondExample,
           thirdExample
          }

          ConcurrentQueue<string> db1 = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();

          [FunctionName("MainOrchestrator")]
          public static async Task<List<String>> RunOrchestrator([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context, ILogger log)
          {
               var outputs = new List<string>();
               dbServerType dbSelection = new dbServerType();
               
               try
               {
                    await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("ActivityMethod1", dbServerSelection);
                    await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("ActivityMethod2", dbServerSelection);
                    await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("ActivityMethod3", dbServerSelection);
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                    log.LogError(ex.Message)
               }
               return outputs;
          }

          [FunctionName("TimerAppStarter")]
          public static async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 0 7 * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer,[DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter, ILogger log)
          {
               log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");


               await starter.StartNewAsync("MainOrchestrator", null);

          }
     }
}
```

As you can see, I have an enum along with some other variables defined within the namespace, however, outside of the Orchestrator / Activity methods called by the orchestrator which I assume is creating some issues. I'm just not sure what the best way to handle the state within this context would be, so any suggestions on how to fix my approach is more than welcome!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Because of  [how Functions v2 handles languages](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Language-Extensibility) the Functions runtime is trying to cast DurableOrchestrationContext to a string.

Unlike v1, v2 executes JavaScript functions via a Node language worker running in a separate process from the runtime host. The gRPC protocol is used to communicate between the language worker and the host.
When a function is called, the runtime host must send the bound parameter information over gRPC to the function. Complex object parameters, such as DurableOrchestrationContext, must be serialised to JSON strings, passed through gRPC, and then rehydrated before being consumed by a function.

Update to the most recent version and try your function again.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Suri. I'm very new to C# let alone Function apps and Durable functions - from what I understand from your reply, I need to update my Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions nuget dependency? It's currently the latest version (3.0.13) though, so I'm still a bit confused.